# el usuario escoja el orden de visualizacion entre columnas

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

lo que quiero es hacer lo siguiente en mi pagina: es que el usuario escoja ver los productos en una columna o dos columnas  como lo hace fallabela:

lo que yo quiero es darle al usuario la opción deque el escoja en una columna dos o tres columnas
lo que quiero es hacer lo siguiente en mi pagina: es que el usuario escoja ver los productos en una columna o dos columnas  como lo hace fallabela:

lo que yo quiero es darle al usuario la opción deque el escoja en una columna dos o tres columnas

```
introducir el código aquí
```

[image: escoge entre el tipo de columna que quiere]

```
    <!--Default Work Column-->
    <div class="default-work-column">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <figure class="image-box"><img src="img/servicio/apertura-de-autos01.webp" alt="Apertura de autos" title="Cerrajero experto en automoviles"></figure>
            <a href="img/servicio/apertura-de-autos01.webp" class="lightbox-image overlay-link"><span class="icon flaticon-cross"></span></a>
            <div class="caption-layer">
                <div class="upper">
                    <h4>Apertura de autos</h4>
                    <div class="category">Cerrajero experto en automoviles</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="options clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#openModal"> SOLICITAR SERVICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tel:3182248888"><span class="icon flaticon-vehicle"></span> LLAMAR AHORA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Default Work Column-->
    <div class="default-work-column hidden-xs">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <figure class="image-box"><img src="img/servicio/apertura-de-autos02.webp" alt="Cerrajería de carros en Bogotá" title="Apertura de Carros en Bogotá"></figure>
            <a href="img/servicio/apertura-de-autos02.webp" class="lightbox-image overlay-link"><span class="icon flaticon-cross"></span></a>
            <div class="caption-layer">
                <div class="upper">
                    <h4>Cerrajería de carros en Bogotá</h4>
                    <div class="category">Apertura de Carros en Bogotá</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="options clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#openModal"> SOLICITAR SERVICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tel:3182248888"><span class="icon flaticon-vehicle"></span> LLAMAR AHORA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Default Work Column-->
    <div class="default-work-column hidden-xs">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <figure class="image-box"><img src="img/servicio/apertura-de-autos03.webp" alt="Profesionales  apertura de Carros" title="Profesionales  apertura de Carros en bogotá"></figure>
            <a href="img/servicio/apertura-de-autos03.webp" class="lightbox-image overlay-link"><span class="icon flaticon-cross"></span></a>
            <div class="caption-layer">
                <div class="upper">
                    <h4>Profesionales  apertura de Carros</h4>
                    <div class="category">Profesionales  apertura de Carros en bogotá</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="options clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#openModal"> SOLICITAR SERVICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tel:3182248888"><span class="icon flaticon-vehicle"></span> LLAMAR AHORA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Default Work Column-->





    <div class="default-work-column">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <figure class="image-box"><img src="img/servicio/apertura-de-camionetass02.webp" alt="Apertura de Camionetas" title="Cerrajería Automotriz en Bogotá"></figure>
            <a href="img/servicio/apertura-de-camionetass02.webp" class="lightbox-image overlay-link"><span class="icon flaticon-cross"></span></a>
            <div class="caption-layer">
                <div class="upper">
                    <h4>Apertura de Camionetas</h4>
                    <div class="category">Cerrajería Automotriz en Bogotá</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="options clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#openModal"> SOLICITAR SERVICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tel:3182248888"><span class="icon flaticon-vehicle"></span> LLAMAR AHORA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Default Work Column-->

</div>
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, por favor si tienes algún código desarrollado colócalo en la para poderte ayudar mejor. Gracias

Comment: Podrías agregar el código en vez de la imagen, es más fácil reproducir el ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: listo compañeros, espero me puedan colaborar